# How to import a CSV with lat/lng columns into a PostgreSQL table with Point column

Tags: sql, postgresql, geolocation, gis

I have a PostgreSQL table that stores geo coordinates using the POINT data type:

```
CREATE TABLE locations (
 id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY,
 name TEXT NOT NULL,
 coord POINT NOT NULL
);
```

I also have my data in form of a CSV file looking as follows

```
id,name,lat,lng
1,A,23.433,132.119
2,B,24.091,132.801
...
```

How can I import the CSV file using `\copy` such that the lat/lng columns are directly converted into the POINT column of the table? Is this possible?

I only came across solutions that load the CSV file into temporary table with lat/lng columns and than create a new table with the POINT column derived from that. I would like to skip this step

Comment: What happens if your file is formatted as id,name,coord with rows as 1,A,(2,3)? Don't have my pg instance handy but looking at the spec that should work.

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible.  You will either need to change the format of the file (possibly on the fly using PROGRAM option), or use the two-step import process.